# Faithful representations and the adjoint representation of a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over a field $k$ with char$(k)\neq 2$. The adjoint representation is a map
$$
\mathrm{ad}:L \to {\frak gl}(V)
$$
whose kernel is the center of $L$. This means that
$$
L/Z(L) \simeq \mathrm{ad}(L)
$$
as Lie algebras. From this we can conclude that
$$
L \simeq Z(L) \oplus \mathrm{ad}(L),
$$
meaning that every Lie algebra is the direct sum of a trivial Lie algebra and a Lie algebra admitting a faithful representation.

The trouble is that this is not true . . .  as far as I can understand from the literature . . .where is my mistake? I guess I have assumed that exact sequences of Lie algebras split . . . which is probably not true!

Comment: "From this we can conclude that" is not true. Not every extension of two Lie algebras is a direct sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in Lie algebras exact sequences do not necessarily split. Take, for instance, the Heisenberg Lie algebra:$$\mathfrak h=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a&c\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\Bbb C\right\}.$$Then,$$Z(\mathfrak h)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&0&c\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,c\in\Bbb C\right\}.$$Furthermore, $[\mathfrak h,\mathfrak h]\subset Z(\mathfrak h)$. So, you can't have $\mathfrak h=Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h)$, since $Z(\mathfrak h)$ is in the center of $Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h)$, and $\bigl[Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h),Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h)\bigr]\not\subset Z(\mathfrak h)$.

Comment: Wait, isn't $\mathrm{ad}(\mathfrak h)$ and hence $\mathrm{ad}(\mathfrak h) \oplus Z(\mathfrak h)$ abelian, so that commutator is $0$? (And the argument is rather that, on the other hand, $\mathfrak h$ is *not* abelian i.e. has smaller centre?)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but what I did is enough to prove that $\mathfrak h$ and $Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h)$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: But then $\bigl[Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h),Z(\mathfrak h)\oplus\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak h)\bigr] =\{ 0 \}\subset Z(\mathfrak h)$.